# Как правильно добавить кусок контента на страницу созданную с помощью блоков Gutenberg?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, есть страница созданная с помощью gutenberg блоков с шаблоном page.php, и в середине страницы есть контент в виде кнопок-ссылок, который как я понимаю с помощью блоков гутенберг не реализовать - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е сверху до кнопок у меня контент построен на блоках гутенберг(заголовки, текст, галерея), внизу видео тоже добавлено в виде блока гутенберг. 
Вопрос: как правильно добавить кнопки в которые показаны на скрине? Page Builder не пользуюсь, тема создана с нуля.

Comment: Ну вставка видео с ютуб в коллекции блоков есть. Создайте свой блок "кнопка" и используйте его для создания кнопок-ссылок. В документации к гутенбергу есть примеры создания своих блоков

Comment: @alenkins Это понятно, добавить ссылку через gutenberg и стилизовать ее - не проблема, вопрос в том как выстроить все эти 10 ссылок в ряд, как это делается через гутенберг, разметка то по сути своей изменяется на странице.